# Store BuildingBlocks in word document via Aspose

Tags: c#, aspose.words

I'm looking for an example to store building blocks in a word document with the Aspose Word Api. And I want to use these building blocks exclusiv in this document.

Has anybody an idea, how this can be realized?

Greetings

Tobi.

Comment: Can you explain more about building block? It will be helpful if you post a sample Word document, we can have a look and guide you how to achieve using Aspose.Words.

Answer (score 0):

If you have MS Word 2013 installed on your machine, you'll most likely find a Word document 'Built-In Building Blocks.dotx' at the following location:

C:\Users\Awais\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Document Building Blocks\1033\15\Built-In Building Blocks.dotx

The predefined built-in building blocks entries that ship with Word are stored in above template document. Using Aspose.Words, you can extract any building block from it, paste inside another Word document and save new document for future use.

GlossaryDocument class in Aspose.Words represents such Building Blocks. Please try using the following code:

```
Document docBuildingBlocks = new Document(MyDir + @"Building Blocks.dotx");
Document doc = new Document(MyDir + @"input.docx");

GlossaryDocument glossaryDocument = docBuildingBlocks.GlossaryDocument;
foreach (BuildingBlock buildingBlock in glossaryDocument.BuildingBlocks)
{
    if (buildingBlock.Gallery.ToString().StartsWith("CoverPage"))
    {
        Section sec = (Section)buildingBlock.FirstChild;
        doc.AppendChild(doc.ImportNode(sec, true));
    }
}

doc.Save(MyDir + @"15.6.0.docx");
```

Hope, this helps.

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.